# QJoysticks краш приложения при использовании Z-Axis

Tags: c++, qt

Подключил QJoysticks в свое приложение и при движении Z-Axis, мое приложение вылетает с ошибкой, хотя я даже не где его не использую.

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ../Qt/5.9.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 549
```

Пробовал кто-то QJoysticks использовать?

ошибка показывает на этот код

```
void QJoysticks::onAxisEvent (const QJoystickAxisEvent& e)
{
    if (!isBlacklisted (e.joystick->id)) {
        getInputDevice (e.joystick->id)->axes [e.axis] = e.value;
        emit axisChanged (e.joystick->id, e.axis, e.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Смотрите отладчиком, в какой строке вылетает, приведенная строка ошибки полностью неинформативна

Comment: Приведенная ошибка говорит о том, что где-то выбивает лист за пределы. Покажите стэк-трейс и код, использующий джойстик

Comment: @goldstar_labs добавил код

Comment: Проверьте размер `axec` из строки `getInputDevice (e.joystick->id)->axes`.

Comment: @gil9red `qDebug() << getInputDevice (e.joystick->id)->axes;` выдает `(0, 0, 0)`, а вот `qDebug() <<  e.axis;` выдает `4`

Comment: т. е. у вас в списке 3 элемента. А вы запрашиваете элемент с индексом 4. Т.к. индексация начинается с 0, то индекс 4 это пятый элемент в списке. Вот поэтому и происходит ошибка выхода за пределы списка

Comment: @gil9red хм, как это пофиксить? код писал не я. это код от Qjoysticks

Comment: @gil9red я так понимаю, нужно увеличить  `QList<double> axes;` только как?

Comment: не знаю, мне этот незнаком и для чего он нужен я тоже не имею понятия, ищите примеры работы. А вы используете библиотеку https://github.com/alex-spataru/QJoysticks?

Comment: есть подозрение, что вы ловите не то событие. и у меня вызывает подозрение тот факт, что `axes` имеет тип `QVector <double>`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver пока что я ничего не ловлю, просто подключил библиотеку и случайно подвинул джойстик и столкнулся с такой ошибкой.

Comment: @gil9red да именно эту библиотеку я пытаюсь использовать.

Comment: @Insider может эта штука заточена под один конкретный джойстик /режим работы джойстика? У меня на usb джойстике есть переключатель сзади - аналоговый/цифровой режим. Там в зависимости от этого по разному оси работают насколько я помню.

Comment: @vegorov попробовал запустить qml example тот что у него на github, с ним работает джойстик нормально. А вот с C++ кодом, что нужно использовать в своем приложении (так же по документации), такие проблемы.

Comment: `if (e.axis >= getInputDevice(e.joystick->id)->axes.size()) return;` Но это попахивает костылем

Comment: напишите автору на гите, его либа - пусть фиксит)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver что-то не понимаю куда это вставлять